# How do I assign "Eigen::EigenSolver<MatrixXd> es(Matrix)" to a variable that I can use later?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3, eigenvector

I am successfully able to retrieve the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from the Eigen::EigenSolver command, however, I cannot assign them to a new Matrix.  I need to assign the 3 eigenvectors to a new 3x3 Matrix so that I can perform a transpose then Matrix Multiplication against another 3x3 matrix.

I keep getting the following Error with a green carrot pointed to the "b" in the "{ a = b; }" part:

*/Eigen/src/Core/functors/AssignmentFunctors.h:24:104: error: assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'const std::__1::complex'
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void assignCoeff(DstScalar& a, const SrcScalar& b) const { a = b; }*

I have tried declaring the new variable I am trying to assign it to as MatrixXd or Vector3d and neither seem to work.  I think the issue has to do with the Eigensolver returning each element as (Real, Complex) and I'm not manipulating this properly.  This would not be a bad thing if I only needed to compute the values once.  However, I am going to need to drop these calculations into a loop and the final calculations from this process will then be checked against some conditionals to determine if the random values used in the code result in valid results.

[EDIT 19April2020, 1152am]. I am only looking to use the Real parts for my current calculations.  Thank you @stark for bringing this to my attention in the comments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Please keep in mind, I'm not a programmer by training, my areas of study are physics and mathematics, and I am used to working with symbolic software and python.
'''

```
// Declare matrices for the up and down type quarks
MatrixXd MatrixYukawaUpQuark(3,3), MatrixYukawaDownQuark(3,3);

// Declare vectors for Up and Down Quark eigenvectors
Vector3d UpQVect, DownQVect;

Eigen::EigenSolver<MatrixXd> es1(MatrixYukawaUpQuark);
UpQVect = es1.eigenvectors(); // THE ERROR COMES FROM HERE, AND IF THIS IS COMMENTED OUT THE CODE WORKS FINE IN GENERATING THE EIGENVECTORS & VALUES IN THE PRINT STATEMENTS 

// Printing the Up Quark Matrice values for the Eigenvectors, and Eigenvalues to the screen
std::cout << "\nThe eigenvalues for the Yukawa Up Quark Matrix are: " << std::endl << es1.eigenvalues() << std::endl;
std::cout << "\nThe Up Quark eigenvectors are:" << std::endl << es1.eigenvectors() << std::endl;

Eigen::EigenSolver<MatrixXd> es2(MatrixYukawaDownQuark);
//DownQVect = es2.eigenvectors(); // THIS WILL ALSO PRODUCE AN ERROR AS IT IS THE SAME PROBLEM FROM ABOVE

// Printing the Up Quark Matrice values for the Eigenvectors, and Eigenvalues to the screen
std::cout << "\nThe eigenvalues of the Yukawa Down Quark Matrix are: " << std::endl << es2.eigenvalues() << std::endl;
std::cout << "\nThe Down Quark eigenvectors, V, is:" << std::endl << es2.eigenvectors() << std::endl;
```

'''

**Below are the print statements that you see above:**

The eigenvalues of the Yukawa Up Quark Matrix are:
(-1.00393,0)
 (1.01004,0)
 (1.00393,0)

The Up Quark eigenvectors are:
 (-0.707819,0)    (0.57735,0)  (-0.407013,0)
  (0.706393,0)    (0.57735,0)  (-0.409483,0)
(0.00142613,0)    (0.57735,0)   (0.816495,0)

The eigenvalues of the Yukawa Down Quark Matrix are:
(-1.96316,0)
 (2.07543,0)
 (1.96316,0)

The Down Quark eigenvectors, V, are:
(-0.713131,0)   (0.57735,0) (-0.397632,0)
 (0.700925,0)   (0.57735,0) (-0.418773,0)
(0.0122058,0)   (0.57735,0)  (0.816405,0)

Comment: So do you just want the real parts?

Comment: apologies for not clarifying this, but yes that would be ideal for now.. perhaps in the future I would look at both.. but thanks again I'll clarify this in my original post

Comment: You don't need to tell me, but you do need to tell the compiler.  It has no way to guess, either.  If you just want the reals, you need a loop and assign the real part to the vector components.

Comment: Generally, please provide a [mre] when seeking help with compiler errors (or wrong results). And there is no need to keep an edit history inside the question -- this can be obtained via [the corresponding link under the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61307903/revisions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a 3x3 complex matrix to a 3x1 real vector. Changing the type of `UpQVect` to `Matrix3cd` should make your code compile:

```
Matrix3cd UpQVect = es1.eigenvectors();
```

If you want to extract the real parts and store them to a 3x3 matrix, you can write:

```
Matrix3d UpQVect = es1.eigenvectors().real();
```

Also note that accessing `es1.eigenvectors()` multiple times is essentially free. The expensive computation happens only when you construct `es1` (or if you would later call `es1.compute(newInput);`.

**But** your matrix appears to be selfadjoint (at least your eigenvector matrix is unitary), so you probably should prefer using the [`SelfAdjointEigenSolver`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html). If your matrix also happens to be known at compile time to have size 3x3, you can even write the much more efficient:

```
Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3d> es1;
es1.computeDirect(MatrixYukawaUpQuark);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, I'll implement these suggestions and report back.  The Matrices being used are very close to being self adjoint, however, this is resulting in calculations later on that do not align with experimental observation, which is one of the reasons why I will be varying certain parameters in each of loops to seek out which values produce results that align with observation.  With that said, implementing SelfAdjointSolver now may hinder me later. I'm going to implement your suggestions now. thanks again!

Comment: Your response was exactly what I was looking for, which is why I have marked it as correct.  Thank you so much, I greatly appreciate it!

Also, I will be implementing the other suggestions and feedback that you and others have made.